# Assign an Instance in a ForeingKey in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I got this kind of error before and I could fix it, but now I don't know what's happening, how can I fix it?

I'm getting:

> Cannot assign "u'2'": "ClosedBets.bet_user_a" must be a "Teams"
>   instance.

My models:

```
class ClosedBets(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match2x1)
    user_a = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="+")
    bet_user_a = models.ForeignKey(Teams,related_name="bet_user_a")
    user_b = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bet_user_b = models.ForeignKey(Teams,related_name='bet')

    def __unicode__(self):
        match = "%s VS %s"%(self.match.team_a,self.match.team_b)
        return match
```

My views:

```
 z = Bets.objects.filter(match_id=request.POST['match']).exclude(user=self.request.user).filter(~Q(bet_id=request.POST['team']),value=request.POST['valor'])
                bet = z.first()
                if bet:
                    print bet.match_id
                    print bet.user_id
                if z: #SI HAY Z
                    ClosedBets.objects.create(match_id=request.POST['match'],user_a=self.request.user,bet_user_a=request.POST['team'],user_b=bet.user_id,bet_user_b=bet.match_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` and `bet_user_a` are foreign keys so you can't assign simple strings/integers to these fields.  So you have to get the instances of FK models from the DB and assign them in the `create()` call:

```
ClosedBets.objects.create(
                   match=Match2x1.objects.get(pk=request.POST['match']),
                   user_a=self.request.user,
                   bet_user_a=Teams.objects.get(pk=request.POST['team']),
                   user_b=bet.user_id,
                   bet_user_b=bet.match_id)
```

Also note that the field in the `ClosedBets` model is called `match` but you trying to create instance with the `match_id` field.